# Prove that a Julia set is symmetric

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-dynamics

I saw the theorem that Julia set of $f(z)=z^2+c$ is symmetric about the origin  and I'm wondering why and how to prove it!

Answer (score 3):

Look at your favourite definition of the Julia set, and note that (since $f(z) = f(-z)$) $z$ satisfies the definition if and only if $-z$ does.

Comment: Isn't in this way it will be a even function rather an odd function symmetric about the origin? because I suppose odd function should be -f(z)=f(-z)?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is an even function.

Comment: So therefore it's not symmetric about origin? Because odd function should be the one which is symmetric about origin

Comment: The graph of the function $f$ would be symmetric about the origin if $f(z) = - f(z)$.   But we're talking about the Julia set, not the graph.